# how to create opaque dataset with a given tag in h5py

Tags: python, hdf5, h5py

I'm trying to recreate an HDF5 file using `h5py` that stores binary data (e.g. JPEG compressed images) as an `OPAQUE` dataset using the tag to store the MIME type so they can be easily decoded later.

The only way I've been able to solve this is using the low-level API, but it would be nice if there was something higher level!

(I'm posting my solution an answer in the hope it's useful to other people as I struggled to find many examples of doing this sort of thing)

Comment: I'm curious - why are you saving as an Opaque dataset? Image data examples I've seen save the images as np.array of various dtypes and shapes.

Comment: @kcw78 jpeg encoding is to save space and opaque datatype seemed appropriate.  expecting to archive ~100k files, each file having ~500 images + related camera/experiment info.

Comment: @kcw78 might have misinterpreted; the format was designed for writing by C++ code (which will produce most of the files) I wanted some python code to do the same for testing and posted the question because it seemed more awkward than I expected

Answer (score 1):

An easier way to solve this issue and avoid the low-level API could be [HDFql](http://www.hdfql.com). In Python using HDFql, it could be solved as follows:

```
# import HDFql package
import HDFql

# create HDF5 file 'output.h5'
HDFql.execute("CREATE FILE output.h5")

# create dataset 'mydata' (in file 'output.h5') of data type opaque with a tag 'image/jpeg' and storing the content of file 'input.jpeg'
HDFql.execute("CREATE DATASET output.h5 mydata TAG image/jpeg VALUES FROM BINARY FILE input.jpeg")
```

Comment: not heard of HDFql before, looks interesting!  is there a way to do this without using the local file system?  AFAICT I could use `variable_transient_register`

Comment: @SamMason: not sure what you mean by local file system. Concerning the usage of `variable_transient_register`, yes, you could use it if you have a NumPy array filled with the content that you want to store in dataset `mydata`. You could then do the following instead: `HDFql.execute("CREATE DATASET output.h5 mydata AS OPAQUE(%d) TAG image/jpeg VALUES FROM MEMORY %d" % (input_size, HDFql.variable_transient_register(my_numpy_array)))`.

Comment: yup, sorry for the ambiguity, you interpreted correctly.  is it valid to pass `bytes` in?  I'm struggling to find a repo (e.g. github) for HDFql so I can check myself, any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I've found of doing this is using the [low level API](http://api.h5py.org/).  This means we need to set up [data types](http://api.h5py.org/h5t.html) and [data spaces](http://api.h5py.org/h5s.html) ourselves before we can create the [dataset](http://api.h5py.org/h5d.html) and [write](http://api.h5py.org/h5d.html#h5py.h5d.DatasetID.write) the data in.

```
import h5py
import numpy as np

# get the binary data in
with open('input.jpeg', 'rb') as fd:
  data = fd.read()

# set up an HDF5 type appropriately sized for our data
dtype = h5py.h5t.create(h5py.h5t.OPAQUE, len(data))
dtype.set_tag(b'image/jpeg')

# set up a simple scalar HDF5 data space
space = h5py.h5s.create(h5py.h5s.SCALAR)

with h5py.File('output.h5', 'w') as root:
  ds = h5py.h5d.create(root.id, b'mydata', dtype, space)

  ds.write(space, space, np.frombuffer(data, dtype=np.uint8), dtype)
```

this works for me, with `h5dump -H output.h5` giving:

```
HDF5 "output.h5" {
GROUP "/" {
   DATASET "mydata" {
      DATATYPE  H5T_OPAQUE {
         OPAQUE_TAG "image/jpeg";
      }
      DATASPACE  SCALAR
   }
}
}
```

but it would be nice if this was a bit easier!